# Нужно отправить данные из формы ajaxom

Tags: javascript

Полученные данные из формы после того как форма прошла проверку нужно отправить ajaxom в контроллер а из его в базу данных.
Пожалуйста помогите
Вот код

```
<form id="registration_form">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="form_fname" name="" required="">
        <span class="error_form" id="fname_error_message"></span>
        <label>
            First Name
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="form_sname" name="" required="">
        <span class="error_form" id="sname_error_message"></span>
        <label>
            Second Name
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="email" id="form_email" name="" required="">
        <span class="error_form" id="email_error_message"></span>
        <label>Email id</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="password" id="form_password" name="" required="">
        <span class="error_form" id="password_error_message"></span>
        <label>Password</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="password" id="form_retype_password" name="" required="">
        <span class="error_form" id="retype_password_error_message"></span>
        <label>Re-Enter Password</label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="register" id="submit"/>
</form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        $("#fname_error_message").hide();
        $("#sname_error_message").hide();
        $("#email_error_message").hide();
        $("#password_error_message").hide();
        $("#retype_password_error_message").hide();

        var error_fname = false;
        var error_sname = false;
        var error_email = false;
        var error_password = false;
        var error_retype_password = false;

        $("#form_fname").focusout(function(){
            check_fname();
        });
        $("#form_sname").focusout(function() {
            check_sname();
        });
        $("#form_email").focusout(function() {
            check_email();
        });
        $("#form_password").focusout(function() {
            check_password();
        });
        $("#form_retype_password").focusout(function() {
            check_retype_password();
        });

        function check_fname() {
            var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;
            var fname = $("#form_fname").val();
            if (pattern.test(fname) && fname !== '') {
                $("#fname_error_message").hide();
                $("#form_fname").css("border-bottom","2px solid #34F458");
            } else {
                $("#fname_error_message").html("Should contain only Characters");
                $("#fname_error_message").show();
                $("#form_fname").css("border-bottom","2px solid #F90A0A");
                error_fname = true;
            }
        }

        function check_sname() {
            var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;
            var sname = $("#form_sname").val()
            if (pattern.test(sname) && sname !== '') {
                $("#sname_error_message").hide();
                $("#form_sname").css("border-bottom","2px solid #34F458");
            } else {
                $("#sname_error_message").html("Should contain only Characters");
                $("#sname_error_message").show();
                $("#form_sname").css("border-bottom","2px solid #F90A0A");
                error_fname = true;
            }
        }

        function check_password() {
            var password_length = $("#form_password").val().length;
            if (password_length < 8) {
                $("#password_error_message").html("Atleast 8 Characters");
                $("#password_error_message").show();
                $("#form_password").css("border-bottom","2px solid #F90A0A");
                error_password = true;
            } else {
                $("#password_error_message").hide();
                $("#form_password").css("border-bottom","2px solid #34F458");
            }
        }

        function check_retype_password() {
            var password = $("#form_password").val();
            var retype_password = $("#form_retype_password").val();
            if (password !== retype_password) {
                $("#retype_password_error_message").html("Passwords Did not Matched");
                $("#retype_password_error_message").show();
                $("#form_retype_password").css("border-bottom","2px solid #F90A0A");
                error_retype_password = true;
            } else {
                $("#retype_password_error_message").hide();
                $("#form_retype_password").css("border-bottom","2px solid #34F458");
            }
        }

        function check_email() {
            var pattern = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
            var email = $("#form_email").val();
            if (pattern.test(email) && email !== '') {
                $("#email_error_message").hide();
                $("#form_email").css("border-bottom","2px solid #34F458");
            } else {
                $("#email_error_message").html("Invalid Email");
                $("#email_error_message").show();
                $("#form_email").css("border-bottom","2px solid #F90A0A");
                error_email = true;
            }
        }

        $("#submit").click(function() {
            error_fname = false;
            error_sname = false;
            error_email = false;
            error_password = false;
            error_retype_password = false;

            check_fname();
            check_sname();
            check_email();
            check_password();
            check_retype_password();

            if (error_fname === false && error_sname === false && error_email === false && error_password === false && error_retype_password === false) {
                submit();
            }


        });
    });

    function submit() {
        $.ajax ({
            url: 'controlers/register.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {'firstname': firstname, 'lastname': lastname, 'email_address': email_address, 'phone_number': phone_number, 'password': password},
            success: function (data) {
                alert('fsijfjs')
            }
        });
    });
    });
```

Comment: Вы решили данный вопрос?

Answer (score 0):

```
     var error_fname = false;
     var error_sname = false;
     var error_email = false;
     var error_password = false;
     var error_retype_password = false;

     var fname;
     ...

     function check_fname() {
        error_fname = false;
        var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;
        fname = $("#form_fname").val();
        if (pattern.test(fname) && fname !== '') {
           $("#fname_error_message").hide();
           $("#form_fname").css("border-bottom","2px solid #34F458");
        } else {
           $("#fname_error_message").html("Should contain only Characters");
           $("#fname_error_message").show();
           $("#form_fname").css("border-bottom","2px solid #F90A0A");
           error_fname = true;
        }
     }

     ...

             $.ajax ({
                 url: 'controlers/register.php',
                 type: 'POST',
                 dataType: 'json',
                 data: {'firstname': fname, ...},
                 success: function (data) {
```

Для остальных значений - аналогично.

---

> if форма == True вызвать функцию function submit()

```
   if (error_fname === false && error_sname === false &&
       error_email === false && error_password === false &&
       error_retype_password === false) {
     submit();
   } else {
     return false;
   }
```

Comment: Это понятно но нужно как то связать что бы если if  форма == True вызвать функцию function submit() {
     $.ajax ({
      url: 'controlers/register.php',
      type: 'POST',